# Implementing Mean Curvature Flow (MCF) for an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to write a Matlab program in which I need to be able to calulate the gaussian gradient of the image, followed by computation of the Mean Curvature Flow (MCF) using this formula :

```
k = {[(Ix^2)(Iyy)] - [2IxIyIxy] + [(Iy^2)(Ixx)]} / {[(Ix^2)(Iy^2)]^ 3/2}
```

I am able to calculate the gaussian gradient but I need some help to understand this formula and suggestions on how I could implement this using Matlab. Any guidance/ help that I can get on this is much appreciated!

Comment: What do all those variables stand for?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309534

Answer (score 1):

You may check [Harris corner detection](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/Spatial/harris.m) part (which is quite similar to yours in means of implementation) of Peter Kovesi's [MATLAB functions for Computer Vision](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/). Particularly this part:

```
% Compute derivatives and elements of the structure tensor.
[Ix, Iy] = derivative5(im, 'x', 'y');
Ix2 = gaussfilt(Ix.^2,  sigma);
Iy2 = gaussfilt(Iy.^2,  sigma);    
Ixy = gaussfilt(Ix.*Iy, sigma);
```

I hope they give intuition for you to implement the formula you give.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you.

```
%mean curvature
```

---

```
function H = MeanCurvature(im)

  Ix = Dx(im); 
  Iy = Dy(im);
  Ixx = Dx(Ix);
  Iyy = Dy(Iy);    
  Ixy = Dx(Iy);
  H = ((1 + Ix.^2).*Iyy - 2*Ix.*Iy.*Ixy+(1 + Iy.^2).*Ixx)./(2*(1 + Ix.^2 + Iy.^2))^(3/2);

end

function d = Dx(u)

  [row,column,p] = size(u);
  d = zeros(row,column,p); 
  d(:,2:column,:) = u(:,1:column-1,:) - u(:,2:column,:);
  d(:,1,:) = u(:,1,:) - u(:,column,:);

end

function d = Dy(u)

  [row, column, p] = size(u);
  d = zeros(row, column, p);
  d(2:row,:,:) = u(1:row-1,:,:) - u(2:row,:,:);
  d(1,:,:) = u(1,:,:)-u(row,:,:);

end
```